# Update an element's property on the main page from within a frame

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, binding, silverlight-4.0

So I have this Main Page (a **UserControl**) containing a **HyperLinkButton** that makes a **Frame** navigate to a certain **Page** (using the **NavigateUri** property from the button). I want to update the **Content** property of this button from within the codebehind of a Page that is displayed in the Frame, whenever a certain event (say, a **Click** event) is triggered on the Page.

Therefore, this Content property has to be reachable from outside the scope of the UserControl containing it... and I cannot seem to be able to make that HyperLinkButton or its Content property static!

I tried using {**Binding**} on the Content property to bind it to some simple static string in my UserControl, but so far this is getting me nowhere... Either I get "non-static" errors when compiling, or the XAML says my string does not exist... Does anyone have a beginning of idea of what I am missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use App.Current.RootVisual to obtain a reference to the MainPage of a silveright navigation project (which is what I'm assuming your project is). From that reference, you can access the Button without resorting to static members and such. You may need to name the HyperLinkButton in your XAML to be able to refer to it from the reference you get to the MainPage.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I finally managed to modify this Button's Content. Just for the record, since my RootVisual is just a home page that serves as the login screen, and redirects to the main page by using LayoutRoot.Children.Add(), I had to do the following to get my main page:

    Home homePage = (Home)App.Current.RootVisual;
    Main mainPage = (Main)homePage.LayoutRoot.Children.First();